# React.js sharing state between components updating a dynamic classname on click rendered from .map function

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state, array.prototype.map

The code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-conditional-class-o1h6sh

The issue:
When you put the child components (Card, Graph) inside the .map function it disrupts the independence of the click, such that clicking either fires all elements, in the case of the 'Card' component or fires both from the 'Graph' component.

The aim:
Be able to click any of the 4 links and envoke the dynamic classname "is-red", changing the text colour on the clicked element leaving the others unaffected but persisting the state of the changed element, i.e have the option to toggle any of the four links on and off, whilst not affecting the toggle state of the others.

---

Passing props to the parent component from two sibling child components works fine, the issue is introduced by the data.map function in addition to nesting the 'Graph' component inside the 'Card' component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Child Component` "Graph" is **inheriting** the `CSS` color style from its `Parent Component` "Card" whenever the "isCardActive" `state` equals true.
you also have the same state `isCardActive` being used for both mapped elements `[{ name: "John" }, { name: "Jane" }]`. When `isCardActive = true` all mapped elements will be affected, not only the clicked one.

**one solution** would be assigning another `className` to the `Child Component`, and moving the `states` inside the `Components` before mapping it. for example :

###### styles.css

```
.is-red {
  color: red;
}
.is-default-color {
  color: black;
}
```

###### Graph.js

```
export default function Graph() {
  const [isGraphActive, setIsGraphActive] = useState(false);
  const handleGraphClick = () => {
    setIsGraphActive((current) => !current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={
          "clicker" + (isGraphActive ? " is-red" : " is-default-color")
        }
        onClick={handleGraphClick}
      >
        Click from Graph
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

###### Card.js

```
export default function Card({ graph, name }) {
  const [isCardActive, setIsCardActive] = useState(false);
  const handleCardClick = () => {
    setIsCardActive((current) => !current);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className={"card__inner" + (isCardActive ? " is-red" : "")}>
        <div className="clicker" onClick={handleCardClick}>
          Click {name} from card
        </div>
        {graph}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

###### App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import Card from "./Card";
import Graph from "./Graph";

const data = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Jane" }];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((el, index) => (
        <Card key={index} name={el.name} graph={<Graph />} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

full sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-conditional-class-forked-068jdx?file=/src/App.js:166-1151)

Comment: Thanks Omar for your reply. I implemented your suggestion/code but still have issues with lack of independence for each link. See updated code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-props-conditional-class-o1h6sh

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope this helps you understanding :)

Comment: Hey Omar, thanks for the sandbox. I am still seeing the same issue? 
If you click on "Click John from card" and then click "Click Jane from card" it toggles the other one off, then you have to click again to toggle the current element (as in two clicks to make it active). So the state doesn't persist independently, same with the "Click from graph" elements? Are you seeing the same thing? 
The intention is for any element to be on or off (red or black) regardless of the state of any other element. 
For example: you should be able to have 3 red and 1 black or all 4 red etc.

Comment: yes, this is happening because you have the same state "isCardActive" for both mapped elements "[{ name: "John" }, { name: "Jane" }]" which are rendered in "<Card />". When "isCardActive = true" all mapped elements will be affected, not only the clicked one. for your case another solution would be creating the states inside the component before mapping it. check the last edits of my answer :)

Comment: Thank you Omar, you were a great help in explaining :)